# `GOTOOLDIR`'s value is set to wrong path after installing `gccgo`. How do I change it back or append path to another directory to it?

Tags: go

After installing `gccgo` the command `go tool toolname` stopped working due to `$GOTOOLDIR` being changed to one used by `gccgo`. It now prints `go tool: no such tool "toolname"` for every tool that is inside `go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/`.

Can I change `$GOTOOLDIR` back to the old value? Or can I append the old value to it so, that `go tool` could look for tools in both directories?